# Script on crontab not being executed but can be executed by itself

Tags: bash, cron, sh

I was trying to schedule this script onto the crontab but the script is not running as expected. I can execute the script manually and it runs as expected generating the list using the command list-users and emails the list but it does not execute when scheduled in the crontab. I have tried to run this script as a .sh file and a .bash file.
This is Script.sh that I am trying to run:

```
echo "Starting script"
list-users primary_number organization.eq.1002 > /var/tmp/ListUserOutput.txt
mail -s 'List Users Org 1002' example@gmail.com < /var/tmp/ListUserOutput.txt
echo "Ending script"
```

This is how it is scheduled in the crontab:

```
0 9 * * * /var/tmp/Script.sh > /var/tmp/Script.log 2>&1
```

And this is the output of the Script.log

```
/bin/sh: /var/tmp/Script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You probably have a carriage return character at the ends of your lines, e.g. if the file was created with a Windows editor.  This is harmless if the script is being executed directly by the shell, but not if you try to run it as a standalone command.  Try filtering the script through `fromdos` or a similar tool.

Comment: I suggest: `dos2unix /var/tmp/Script.sh`

Comment: As an aside, the temporary file can easily be avoided; use a pipe.

Comment: The name of the file doesn't matter, though using `.sh` on files which are not `sh` scripts is confusing to human readers. A general convention is for scripts to not have an extension at all.